# The APIs request should be made from 1 ip address only

Tags: java, android, json, api

Hi so I'm developing an Android app and using APIs of erail.in but the condition Is that all the request should be made from 1 ip address. As the users who will be using my app will have different ip address. How do I solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Route the requests to a central controller which then forwards them with his own IP address

Answer (score 4):

You can insert a node that operate as a bridge.
Basically something like that

```
   Client1       Client2      Client3
      |             |            |
      +-------------+------------+
                    |
                    |
                 Bridge
                    |
                    |
           API accepting from 1 IP
```

As suggested by @Skynet the bridge node can be used not only as a bridge, but also for other things, for example:

- cache level
- pre-authentication
- logger of requests
- api request counter

Comment: Apart from what Davide suggested, better also implement a cache - If the data does not get stale over time.

Comment: @Skynet thanks for your suggestion, I updated the answer taking in consideration that